# Custom IPTables ruleset in openshift-ansible

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

Is it possible to add a custom iptables ruleset in openshift-ansible? If yes, where and what should be edited ?

Thanks again,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still looking for a solution to this, the suggested method that involves Ansible is to create a wrapper playbook that invokes the os_firewall role.

The suggestion comes from a RedHat Solutions document: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2695741

Also worth pointing out, the role is in the OpenShift Ansible package and ends up in /usr/share/ansible/openshift-ansible/roles/lib_os_firewall.